# How to change properties of an inputbox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm doing a small project to make a system to library. And for it,I'm handling an input box. When I type an ISBN number in the box,the value passes to another form very accurately. Here is the C# code.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbtnISBNNo.Checked == true) 
        {
            ISBNNo = Interaction.InputBox("Enter your ISBNNo.....", "Enter ISBNNo", "", -1, -1);
            SearchRes FrmSearchRes = new SearchRes();
            FrmSearchRes.Show();
        }
```

This works perfectly fine and here is screenshot of the inputbox.

[image]

The problem is,I need to customize this inputbox. It's size,font,color and other properties. How can I do it? Please help!

Comment: There is no easy way to achieve this. It would be easier to implement your own inputbox by creating a simple form with a textbox and applying whatever fonts, color and style you want.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya is right, input box is a standart OS managed component, just like open file dialog. As such it provides very limited customization. You should totally create your own form

Comment: Thank you for helping.I made a simple form and customized it..It was kind of easy.

Answer (score -2):

Click <kbd>F4</kbd> on Input and by using "Properties" you find

[image]